# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, password

Im trying to to dump an old database system to migrate the data.

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.32, for pc-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2
```

The weird part is this:

```
# mysql -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
#
```

As you can see, the mysql client does not prompt me for the password, despite me having set -p. Same thing happens with --password. Anything I can do to fix this?
mysqldump behaves in the same way by the way.

Comment: Is this a new mysql installation ?

Comment: no. old installation that has a production system running on it

Comment: So you have a production env with no access to it ? how come ?

Comment: Alter the root password using the mysqladmin tool!

Comment: I was mainly thinking this would be some kind of bug within the mysql client because I am clearly asking it to prompt me for a password but it just doesn't